# TextInput as ItemRenderer in DataGrid :Scroll Issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datagrid, itemrenderer

I use textInput as ItemRenderer for all columns of a  datagrid.I need to set editability of  first  row as false.I did it on creationComplete of the itemRenderer.Also tried overriding upDateDislayList.
 It works fine for the first row.But some other rows also get their editability changed to false.Also on scroll many rows get their editability changed.Please help.

> ```
>   override public function set data(value:Object):void
>     { 
>         super.data = value; 
>       if(listData.owner.name == "headCountGrid")
>       {
>       if(data != null && qbpHttpServ.rowDataHcGridArr != null)
>           { 
>              if(data["column1Data"] == qbpHttpServ.rowDataHcGridArr[0]["column1Data"])
>           {
>           this.editable = false;
>           }
>           }
>      }
>     }
>     override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void{
>      super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
>      var g:Graphics = graphics;
>      g.clear();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Check this link, should help http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know that items in lists are reused? Make sure they are controlled entirely by set data() function. Pass editability flag with data.

Comment: yes i do.saw that in action :)I had a set data() function.I  handled editability here.The same problem persists.

Comment: i have edited the question to include the code.thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I see. Editability is never set to true. Items get reused with editable off. Make sure you always set it to true or false, don't skip it.